# Limit concurrent Web Service request (Or some batch approach)

Tags: web-services, scala, asynchronous, playframework, playframework-2.0

I've a for comprehension that fetches a comma separated Id List from a web service.
Then I use the Id List to make new calls, my problem here is that the Id List can be around 10 000 long and each call is a medium sized XML document.
The Web Service end point, or it could be the Play Framework, does't quite like it when I request all the 10 000 at the same time asynchronously as I only get around 500 correct responses.

Some pseudo code to highlight the intent.

```
for {
  respA <- WS.url(url1).get
  id <- respA.body.split(",")
  respB <- WS.url(url2 + id).get
} yield ...
```

How do I get about to limit the concurrent request to something more feasible?

Comment: I think you should first identify where the problem actually is.  Is there something wrong with `WS` in Play or is there something wrong with the end point.  Is the endpoint throwing HTTP errors at some point?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Here is an example app that batches 10,000 requests (via Play's WS library) into groups of 1,000 - all in an async & non-blocking way:

```
package controllers

import play.api.libs.concurrent.Promise
import scala.concurrent.duration._
import play.api.libs.ws.WS
import scala.concurrent.{Await, Future}
import scala.concurrent.ExecutionContext.Implicits.global
import play.api.mvc.{Action, Controller}
import play.api.libs.ws.Response
import play.api.Logger

object Application extends Controller {

  var numRequests = 0

  def index = Action {
    Async {
      val batches: Iterator[Seq[WS.WSRequestHolder]] = requests.grouped(1000)

      val allBatchesFutureResponses = batches.foldLeft(Future.successful(Seq.empty[Response])) { (allFutureResponses, batch) =>
        allFutureResponses.flatMap { responses =>
          val batchFutures = Future.sequence(batch.map(_.get))
          batchFutures.map { batchResponses =>
            responses ++ batchResponses
          }
        }
      }

      allBatchesFutureResponses.map { responses =>
        Logger.info(responses.size.toString)
        Ok
      }
    }
  }

  def requests = (1 to 10000).map { i =>
    WS.url("http://localhost:9000/pause")
  }

  def pause = Action {
    Async {
      Logger.info(numRequests.toString)
      numRequests = numRequests + 1
      Promise.timeout(Ok, 1 seconds)
    }
  }

}
```

Answer (score 7):

You need to do some sort of throttling.

#### Akka

How about using some Akka Actors to make the requests?  Check out these approaches to throttling with akka:

- Have a number of child `Actor`s equal to the amount of concurrent requests you want to make. Each child actor sends a response to the parent `Actor` on completion of the HTTP request Future. Each time a child `Actor` responds, send it the next request to make.
- Use Akka's `TimerBasedThrottler` to drip feed messages to child `Actor`s that make the HTTP requests: http://doc.akka.io/docs/akka/2.1.2/contrib/throttle.html
- https://stackoverflow.com/a/9615080/936869

#### Just with Futures

If you want to just use `Future`s and no Akka `Actor`s, you could use a combination of `flatMap` (to chain up HTTP requests to happen one after another) and `Future.sequence` to get the level of parallelism you want.

Answer (score 0):

You could consider batching the calls into the second web service and only moving on to subsequent batches after the previous batch has completed.  That approach could look like this:

```
val fut = for {
  ids <- WS.url(url1).get.map(res => res.body.split("").grouped(batchSize).toList)   
  responses <- processBatches(ids)
} yield responses

fut onComplete{
  case Success(responses) => //handle responses
  case Failure(ex) => //handle fail
}

def processBatches(batches:List[Array[String]]) = {
  val prom = Promise[List[Response]]()
  var trys = List[List[Response]]()

  def doProcessBatch(remainingBatches:List[Array[String]]) {      
    val batch = remainingBatches.head
    val futs = batch.map(id => WS.url(url2 + id).get).toList
    Future.sequence(futs) onComplete{ tr =>
      val list = tr.getOrElse(List()) //add better error handling here
      trys = list :: trys
      if (remainingBatches.size > 1) doProcessBatch(remainingBatches.tail)
      else prom.success(trys.flatten)
    }      
  }
  doProcessBatch(batches)
  prom.future
}
```

The idea hare is to hit the first service to get the ids list and then break that into batches determined by some batch size that you select.  Then, work those batches, sending batchSize number of concurrent calls to the second ws call, waiting until all have completed before moving to the next batch.  When done, you will have a `Future` with a `List[Response]` representing all of the calls made to the second service.  This is not production ready code as it needs better handling for failures (I'm just returning an empty list in that case).  It also probable needs to chain a call to `recover` after `get` on this line:

```
val futs = batch.map(id => WS.url(url2 + id).get).toList
```

to prevent one failure in the batch from causing you to lose the rest of the results from that batch, but I'll leave that stuff up to you.  I just wanted to show you a high level concept for batching the calls into the second service to as to non inundate it with calls.

Answer (score -2):

Use a thread pool. The following URL describes the whole mechanism: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms973903.aspx

Comment: I'm already using a thread pool of 8 (one per core). The "problem" here is that Play framework is non blocking asynchronously and can handle multiple request per thread.

Comment: Well, you could then use blocking requests with a much larger thread pool (start with 20 as a baseline). A number of threads equal to the number of available cores maximize performance for CPU intensive tasks. However, having a larger number of threads can be used for blocking operations such as IO or web service requests.

Comment: It's certainly an option, but then you'd lose all the advantages on async IO. Why not avoid a large number of needless memory hogging threads when possible.